# What happens to centripetal acceleration if you change speed while rounding a corner?

Tags: acceleration, speed, centripetal-force

What happens to centripetal acceleration if you change speed while rounding a corner?

Comment: Is there a particular idea that you don't understand? This question is too vague. It depends on what path you take around the corner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The centripetal acceleration continues to be controlled by the same expression you used for constant speed, it is just that this is now a function of time.
$$\begin{align*}
 a_c &= a_c(t)\\
&= \frac{v^2(t)}{r} \,.
\end{align*}$$
At the same time, the changing of the speed implies a tangential acceleration
$$\begin{align*} 
a_t &= \frac{\mathrm{d} \left|v(t)\right|}{\mathrm{d}t} \\
&\approx \frac{\Delta |v|}{\Delta t} \,, 
\end{align*}$$
which means that the total acceleration now points to the inside of the circle but not toward the center anymore.